# Stepping MVC Mini Profiler without nested usings

Tags: c#, crm, dynamics-crm-4, mvc-mini-profiler

We're modelling a complicated system based around a complicated entity relationship in Dynamics CRM 4.0

Due to the nature of development we've had to implement a repository style pattern and have lots of different providers that relate to each other.

What I really want to do is to profile their constructors and various lazy getters, but I want to model this at the top level possible.

The problem is, of course, Scope - If I wrap the constructor in a using block, it's not available to anything else. If I extend the using block so that everything that references the object I'm profiling comes into scope, then the profiler isn't just profiling the constructor - it's timing everything else.

Similarly, there's a level of nesting, If I nest the usings correctly, then the code becomes unreadable.

I've had a look at Profiler.Inline but that doesn't serve my purposes.

What I'd really like to do is this:

```
ref = Profiler.StartStep("Creating CRM Model");
//Do horrible CRM work
var myNewHorribleObject = CRM.ModelHorribleStuff(...);
Profiler.StopStep(ref);

ref = Profiler.StartStep("How long does it take to get X");
var data = Repository.GetSomething(myNewHorribleObject.SomeId);
Profiler.StopStep(ref);

ref = Profiler.StartStep("How long does it take to get Y");
var newData = Repository.GetSomethingElse(myNewHorribleObject.ContextId);
Profiler.StopStep(ref);
```

Does that make sense ? Hopefully I'm overlooking something in Mini Profiler, but I'd welcome  any suggestions!

I would like to remodel the code a bit, but there is no time for that and whilst it looks odd, we actually have a pretty good cyclomatic complexity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Instead of using the `using` just use "MiniProfiler.Current.Step("blah")". This will return an object that implements `IDisposeable`. When that object is actually disposed of is when the timings will stop. You can even nest things with `using` statements just like normal.

Example:

```
 IDisposable executingStep;
 executingStep= MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Some code after this");
 // do long code
 Thread.Sleep(100);
 using (profiler.Step("Step 2313"))
 {
     Thread.Sleep(100);
 }
 executingStep.Dispose();
```

Comment: Note that if MiniProfiler is not started then executingStep will be null, so you will need "if (executingStep != null) executingStep.Dispose()" for this case.